# Angular Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for service

Tags: angular, typescript

I don't understand why this service doesn't work? Is it some problem with dependencies?

service:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

export class GetWeatherService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getWeather() {
        return this.http.get(link);
    }
}
```

and component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GetWeatherService } from './get-weather.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-form',
    templateUrl: './form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./form.component.css'],
    providers: [GetWeatherService]
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public getWeather: GetWeatherService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getWeather.getWeather();
    }
}
```

Comment: hagner's answer is what you need, but may I also suggest using the new HttpClient instead of 'Http'. It has a number of improvements :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your service injectable:

```
@Injectable()
export class GetWeatherService {
    //CODE
}
```

Comment: I thought I was adding Injectable decorator when I want inject dependency to this service from another service. Thank's a lot. It works. Greetings

Answer (score 2):

Add `@Injectable()` over your service to let it be injected into constructors.

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class GetWeatherService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getWeather() {
        return this.http.get(link);
    }
}
```